# Excluding children of "label" tag using XPath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I've read similar posts regarding the matter and tried different approaches but can not solve this one. Executing line below returns content of both parent (label) and a child (span). ex. Required Field Rewards Number

```
List <WebElement> oRequiredFields = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'is-field')]"));
```

What do I need to add to my code in order to only return content of the parent (ex. Rewards Number)

```
<label for="field-account-id" class="is-field is-required">
    <i class="icon icon-asterisk t-form-asterisk"></i>
        <span class="is-hidden-text">Required Field</span>
            Rewards Number
</label>`
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This `driver.findElements(By.xpath(//label[text()='Rewards Number']))`

Comment: Thank you S Ravikumar but there are more than one field I need to grab. I can not hard code 'Rewards Number'